# Wordpress The Grid plugin filter using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I am currently having troubles with the grid plugin, when you select a filter it only filters the data that has already been loaded. I wanted it to filter all contents from the database. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.tg-filter-name').on('click',function () {
    if (window.tg_ajax) {

        tg_global_var.main_query.filters_onload = []
        tg_global_var.main_query.active_filters = []

        var el = $('div.tg-grid-holder');
        var tag_id = $(this).closest('.tg-filter').data('filter').replace('.f',''),$filter = $(this),tax= $filter.closest('.tg-filter').data('taxo')
        if ($(this).closest('.tg-filter').hasClass('tg-filter-active')) {
            for(var x =0; x < tg_global_var.main_query.filters_onload.length; x++) {
                if (tg_global_var.main_query.filters_onload[x] == tax + ':' + tag_id) tg_global_var.main_query.filters_onload.splice(x,1)
            }
            for(x = 0; x < tg_global_var.main_query.active_filters.length; x++) {
                if (tg_global_var.main_query.active_filters[x] == tag_id) tg_global_var.main_query.active_filters.splice(x,1)   
            }
        } else {
            tg_global_var.main_query.filters_onload.push(tax + ':' + tag_id)
            tg_global_var.main_query.active_filters.push(tag_id)
        }

        var data = {
            action: 'the_grid_load_more',
            grid_nonce: tg_global_var.nonce,
            grid_name: el.data('name'),
            grid_page: tg_global_var.main_query.page,
            main_query: tg_global_var.main_query
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: tg_global_var.url,
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (resp) {
                el.html(resp.content)
            }
            })
        }
    } )
} )
```

I've also tried adding a `tax_query` to the `main_query` variable on my post request. Anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: did you figure this out? i need to build the same functionality

Comment: sorry, dropped the plugin entirely.

Comment: never mind. We decide to display all the content without pagination and it's working for us.